# Intentional Infeasible Linear Program in Rsymphony

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, linear-programming

I am using the `Rsymphony` package in R for an mixed integer program.  I would like to be able to iteratively relax one of my constraints until the problem becomes feasible.  To do so, I'd like to be able to:

1. send the MILP's constraint matrix, objective function, etc. to the SYMPHONY solver via `Rsymphony_solve_LP`
2. if `Rsymphony_solve_LP` returns a feasible solution (or states that there *is* a feasible solution) then I would terminate the solve, rebuild my constraint matrix with a tighter constraint, then re-send to the solver via `Rsymphony_solve_LP`
3. If `Rsymphony_solve_LP` says the problem is infeasible, I backtrack to the last feasible constraint matrix and solve from there.

Any tips/tricks on how to do this without just manually watching the solver with verbosity on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A poster on a different board gave a good approach. I reformulated the MILP so that the constraint I want to iterate, is multiplied by a 'tuning parameter' continuous decision variable. I will put a penalty term associated with that decision variable into the objective function to relax the constraint as little as possible. The effect should be that the constraint is relaxed enough to be feasible, but not beyond that.